# CUDA emulator for windows 7

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I have read several related posts but while some of them are for emulators on linux, others are on specific versions of windows with some preferences. So, I want to keep it simple: Is there a CUDA emulator that runs on windows. If yes, please provide me the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GPUOcelot](http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/) has a section about the "experimental" windows build in the [installation wiki](http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/wiki/Installation).

---

Edit in 2021 to note that while Ocelot was a very impressive student research project, all the original authors moved on to other things many years ago and active development has ceased.

It is very unlikely that the code, which is still available on github, could be made to work with anything other than circa 2011 CUDA toolkits and their supported host toolchains.

Comment: does this "experimental" build work. Moreover, should i download the CUDA toolkit or i dont need it

Comment: I haven't used it, but Ocelot definitely works -- you just have to get it building for Windows.  It is a PTX emulator, so you need the CUDA toolkit to compile your code to PTX.  There is no other CUDA emulator that I know of, unless you revert to pre-3.0 CUDA which had a device emulation mode.

Comment: Linux, I believe.  I suggest checking out the website for full details.  The real question is, why do you need a CUDA emulator?

Comment: Actually, i need to do some programming on the NVIDIA gpu that supports the cuda architecture and i have a windows machine

Comment: Then it sounds like you don't need an emulator at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is this one: https://code.google.com/p/cuda-waste/
You need to install the CUDA toolkit